# Python - value unpacking order in method parameters

Tags: python, unpack, argument-unpacking

```
def fun(a, b, c, d):
    print('a:', a, 'b:', b, 'c:', c, 'd:', d)
```

why this one works

```
fun(3, 7, d=10, *(23,))
```

and prints out:

```
a: 3 b: 7 c: 23 d: 10
```

while this

```
fun(3, 7, c=10, *(23,))
```

does not

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lookash/PycharmProjects/PythonLearning/learning.py", line 10, in <module>
    fun(3, 7, c=10, *(23,))
TypeError: fun() got multiple values for argument 'c'
```

Comment: I don't know the exact reason that error is thrown, but you should never have variable arguments after keyword arguments. Normally an error is thrown but tuple unpacking seems to throw a different error than the normal `SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument`.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse. I think you're missing the point. OP has found a case where you can actually put a positional after a keyword, and it works.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I see that. But I was more just making a statement that tuple unpacking shouldn't take place after keyword arguments. Thus I made it as a comment not an answer.

Comment: Awesome question. Never knew this was a thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `*(23,)`, you are unpacking the values in the tuple `(23,)` as positional arguments, following the positional arguments that are already defined, namely `3` for `a` and `7` for `b`, so `23` would be assigned to parameter `c`, which is why `fun(3, 7, d=10, *(23,))` works, but in `fun(3, 7, c=10, *(23,))` you are also assigning to value `10` to `c` as a keyword argument, so it is considered a conflict as `c` cannot be assigned with both `23` and `10`.

Note that while legal, it is discouraged by some to unpack iterable arguments after keyword arguments, as discussed [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue38560), although the syntax is ultimately ruled to stay.

Comment: It's clear what's happening, but since when can you unpack positionals after keywords?

Comment: Since Python 3.

Comment: Do you have a source for that? It it intentional and documented, or arguably a bug/omission?

Comment: Tuple unpacking must take place before keyword arguments in terms of order of operation. Could be a an omission...

Comment: @MadPhysicist My bad. I was thinking of something else. This syntax is actually legal in Python 2 as well. The primary use case, as evident from the CPython test case of `f(1,2,c=3,*d,**e)` in [test_ast.py](http://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/test/test_ast.py#L207), is to allow a wrapper function to pass variable arguments and keyword arguments to the wrapped function in a more intuitive way, by placing both the variable arguments and variable keyword arguments in the end of the argument list.

Comment: @blhsing. Yup, read the bug report, which GvR said is not a bug. Nice to know one more piece of Python arcana. Now that it's pretty clear this isn't going away any time soon, I can't wait to start using it inappropriately :)

Comment: Could you put the link back into your answer? I think it makes for a very useful source.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Rolled back the edit as suggested, though I do think GvR's decision is right since the use case of a wrapper function as I described above is quite legitimate indeed.

Comment: @blhsing. Agreed. I don't think there's anything there that makes this syntax inviolate.